# Sed removing duplicate characters and certain characters in beginning/end of string

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I am asking for your help with sed. I need to remove duplicate underscores and underscores from beginning and end of string.

For example:

> `echo '[Lorem] ~ ipsum *dolor* sit metus !!!' | sed 's/[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789._()-]/_/g'`

Produces:
`_Lorem____ipsum__dolor__sit_metus____`

But I need to further format this string to: `Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_metus`

In other words, remove any underscores from beginning and end of string, and reduce multiple consecutive underscore symbols into just one, preferably using another pipes.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: In a POSIX regex, the string '[:alnum:]' will work in place of your writing out the alphanumeric possibilities.  Eg. 's/[^[:alnum:]._()-]/_/g'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `;s/__*/_/g;s/^_//;s/_$//` just after `g` in your sed command.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a "+" after your bracket expression to eliminate runs of multiple underscores. Then you can delete the beginning and ending ones. Also, as **ladenedge** suggested, you can use a character class to shorten your list.

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:].()-]\+/_/g;s/^_\(.*\)_$/\1/'
```